# Why the document.getElementById('textbox') is null in javascript after C# already assigned it?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I already created a textbox id called `txt` which it empty at the start. After I click button, the C# assigned information from user input to txt.Text and it did display the result in txt textbox then calling the javascript function and I use `document.getElementById('txt');` to get value that is already displayed. However the javascript is showing that the `txt` is null even the information is already displayed on textbox. I tried with alert, it does trigger when calling that function. I don't understand why?

C# codes,

```
protected void ButtonRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //more codes, I cut this short to main point        

         txt.Text = deviceName;

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "call", "<script>CreateIsm();</script>", false);
    }
```

In asp.net and javascript,

```
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" CodeBehind="~/Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>



    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
         // global variables
            id = 'AUTH';
            notes = '';
            ismClassId = '';
            caseType = '';
            l1 = '';
            l2 = '';
            l3 = '';


              // Create ISM Ticket
            CreateIsm = function (funct) {

                // alert("hello");
                var textBox = document.getElementById('txt');
                var txt = "Please add the following DNS entries\n" + textBox;


                ismClassId = 'ServerName';
                caseType = 'Request';
                l1 = 'Request';
                l2 = 'Network';
                l3 = 'Static IP Address';

                notes = txt;
                //notes = $('#txt').val();

                $.support.cors = true;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://serversite/SubmissionPage.aspx",
                    data: {
                        'Form_ID': '08.01.7',
                        'ISM_Class_ID': ismClassId,
                        'Case_Type': caseType,
                        'Level_1': l1,
                        'Level_2': l2,
                        'Level_3': l3,
                        'Case_Notes': notes,
                        'Contact_ID': id
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //console.log(data);
                        var str = data;
                        var ticket = $(str).find("#ticketIDOutput").val();
                        var hreff = "http://egsd.jvservices.com/Form/SRApproval/SRApproval.aspx?ticketID=" + ticket;
                        var a = "<a href='" + hreff + "' target='blank'>" + ticket + "</a> created."
                        $('#output').html(a);

                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        $('#output').html("Error creating ISM ticket: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });

            }  
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <center>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonRequest" runat="server" onclick="ButtonRequest_Click" 
        Text="Request" Visible="False" style="height: 26px" />
       <br />
        <br />
        <div id="output">
        </div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" visible="true" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                    Width=356px Height=200px style="margin-left: 0px"></asp:TextBox>
    </center>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `txt` the client-side ID as well?  Does it exist in the page when the page is rendered?  Does it exist *before* the JavaScript code which tries to use it?  (That order is important in JavaScript, you can't reference something that doesn't exist until later in the page since JavaScript is executed as it's read by the engine.)

Comment: txt is client side ID. But still, the C# already assigned to `txt.Text` before calling the javascript to get the `txt` information that C# already assigned.

Comment: The error isn't a server-side error, so stop thinking in terms of server-side code.  Examine (and include in the question) the rendered client-side markup of the `input` element, as well as its placement in relation to the JavaScript code being executed.  We're not going to just take your word for it on any of this, you need to include the client-side code in the question.

Comment: It already included javascript and html as client-side code

Comment: No, you haven't.  You've included the server- side ASP.NET markup, not the client-side HTML markup.  Again, this is a *client-side* error.  While there may be a server-side fix, to diagnose the problem you need to at least *examine* the client-side code.  You also have yet to indicate the order in which these things exist on the client.  If the JavaScript executes before the input element even exists, it won't find it.  We can't debug this for you if you won't provide useful information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access ClientID

```
var textBox = document.getElementById('<%=txt.ClientID %>');
```

If you are using .Net framework 4.0 or higher you can use [ClientIDMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your control.

In your aspx page specify ClientIDMode = "Static" wiht your control like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server" visible="true" TextMode="MultiLine" 
 Width=356px Height=200px style="margin-left: 0px"></asp:TextBox>
```

and then you can access it like:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById('txt');
```

Comment: Open your web page in chrome, right click near your TextBox and click inspect element, see the ID assigned to the TextBox,

Comment: It assigned to `txt` but it really strange that chrome is recognize textarea instead of textbox.... like this `<textarea name="txt" rows="2" cols="20" id="txt" style="height:200px;width:356px;margin-left: 0px"></textarea>`. I use IE

Comment: @StudentIT, you have `MultiLine` set, so you will always get `TextArea` surprising thing is that the id you are getting is `txt`, it should work with `var textBox = document.getElementById('txt');`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the markup generated in your browser.. you'll see that the ID isn't actually what you think it is.

You can force it to be what you want.. by setting the `ClientIDMode` to `Static`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" visible="true" TextMode="MultiLine" 
        Width=356px Height=200px style="margin-left: 0px" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Or you could use the `ClientID` property of the control in your page code.

Comment: Can you confirm the ID of your element is definitely `txt` in the markup (browser rendered markup)?